# Tracking process of unknown origin, on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need some out-of-the-box thinking on this issue. It's weird.

I have a SQL Server environment (production) where I get a sporadic error executing a procedure.

```
dbo.proc_1_$sp
...
begin try
  BEGIN
      SELECT @errmsg = 'failed to execute proc2_$sp'
    EXEC proc2_$sp; 
  END; 
...
catch
... etc
```

EXEC proc2_$sp fails.

It returns error

> failed to execute proc2_$sp

to a process log table.

The problem is... I don't execute `dbo.proc_1_$sp`.

I want to find out what executes it. It could be a test environment pointing to production, it could be a test script someone left running.

I want to know the hostname, the login name, or whatever info I can catch on this process.

I can't leave SQL Server Profiler trace on. I tried, but it's a prod environment and I can't let the trace running for hours.

The only way I can think of is to update the error message with more info, as below.

The problem is, since I don't know the login name, I can't ensure the user will have access to `sys.sysprocesses` and I might get a crash instead.

Any other suggestions on how I can grab process information without worrying about permission issues?

```
dbo.proc_1_$sp
...
begin try
  BEGIN
      SELECT @errmsg = 'failed to execute proc2_$sp'
      
      select @errmsg = @errmsg + ' login_time:'+convert(nvarchar, login_time, 9)+' hostname:'+ltrim(rtrim(hostname)) + ' program_name:'+ltrim(rtrim(program_name))+' loginame:'+loginame 
        FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE spid = @@SPID
    EXEC proc2_$sp; 
  END; 
...
catch
... etc
```

Comment: `sys.sysprocesses` is deprecated but the documentation indicates that users can always see info about their own session https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysprocesses-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks

Comment: `sys.dm_exec_connections` and `sys.dm_exec_sessions` maybe? Unclear exactly what info you want and whether it's executed under the same session

Comment: Thank you, I think sys.dm_exec_sessions might do the trick, I just need the username and hostname mostly.